# Android ListView and Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Specific problem is a failure to call the getView method of my custom arrayadapter.
I use a Fragment to display a List.  The Activity that spawns the list allows a person to be selected from a spinner.  I then retrieve data from a DB using the id of the selected person.  I package this data in a custom holder object which is assigned to an ArrayList.  Following is the activity code that creates a fragment transaction.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

NotesListViewFragment notesListViewFragment = new NotesListViewFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.NOTES_LIST, (ArrayList) rowValues);
notesListViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.add(notesListViewFragment, "FRAG");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The fragment correctly gets the bundled data. The onCreate method executes correctly, as does the onCreateView method. Following is the onCreateView code:

```
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_list_fragment_layout, null);
    ListView notesListView = (ListView) 
view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //ListView notesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android:list);

notesListView.addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_list_headings, 
    container, false));
View footer = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.notes_list_footer, null);
TextView v = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.total_notes);
v.setText(Integer.toString(notesList.size()));
v.setTypeface(font);
footer.setPadding(30, 25, 0, 0);
notesListView.addFooterView(footer);

CustomNotesListAdapter adapter = new CustomNotesListAdapter(context,
            R.layout.notes_list_row_layout, notesList);
            //R.layout.notes_list_row_layout, notesList, false);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
//setListAdapter(adapter);

return view;
```

After the adapter is created it contains the data in the 'notesList'.
The adapter constructor and the getCount method is called which returns the correct number of rows.  The getView method is never called and nothing is displayed on the device.  Here is the getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
NoteListHolder noteListHolder = getItem(position);

if (convertView == null) {
    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                //.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_image);
        viewHolder.noteText = (TextView) 
  convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
        viewHolder.updatedDate = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.updated_date);
        viewHolder.updatedBy = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.updated_date);
        viewHolder.noteSource = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_source);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.noteText.setText(noteListHolder.getNote());
    viewHolder.noteSource.setText(noteListHolder.getNoteSource());
    viewHolder.updatedDate.setText(noteListHolder.getLastUpdated());
    viewHolder.updatedBy.setText(noteListHolder.getLastUpdatedBy());

    return convertView;
```

Here is the ListView xml layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    style="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >
```

I have five or six similar scenarios in the app, all working correctly.  The only difference is the use of a Fragment to contain the List.

Hope someone has the patience to read this and thanks for any ideas.

Comment: what happens if you delete the `if (convertView == null)` check?

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
if(convertView) {
...
}
```

You want to inflate your layoutResourceId

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, true);
...
return rowView;
```

Comment: Thanks. But getView method is not being called so it never gets to the suggested code.

Comment: Replicating frag code in an Activity and using intent to fire activity, everything works as intended, so what is so special about a frag?